# Speech recognition for Asterisk

Tags: speech-recognition, asterisk

http://zaf.github.io/asterisk-speech-recog/

```
;;Simple speech recognition
exten => 1234,1,Answer()
exten => 1234,n,agi(speech-recog.agi,en-US)
exten => 1234,n,Verbose(1,The text you just said is: ${utterance})
exten => 1234,n,Verbose(1,The probability to be right is: ${confidence})
exten => 1234,n,Hangup()
```

But it gives the following result:-

```
The text you just said is: -1
The probability to be right is: -1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double check that you have all the dependencies installed.

```
Perl: The Perl Programming Language 
perl-libwww: The World-Wide Web
library for Perl flac: Free Lossless Audio Codec
```

An example of packages installed on CentOS for one of my implementations of this Google Speech Recognition API, AGI script:

```
[user@box ~]$ sudo rpm -qa | grep -Pi "libwww|flac|^perl\-\d"
perl-libwww-perl-5.833-2.el6.noarch
flac-devel-1.2.1-6.1.el6.x86_64
perl-5.10.1-130.el6_4.x86_64
flac-1.2.1-6.1.el6.x86_64
```